# attribute groups does not belong to object

Tags: python

The following code works as expected if I declare the "line" variable at the beginning of the script. something like ...

```
s = "Jul 15 12:12:51 whitelist logger: 1|999999999999|id:d9faff7c-4016-4343-b494-37028763bb66 submit date:1307130919 done date:1307130919 stat:DELIVRD err:0|L_VB3_NM_K_P|1373687445|vivnel2|L_VB3_GH_K_P|promo_camp1-bd153424349bc647|1"
```

When I open a file and loop through lines, the groups attribute does not work. I get an error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

```
# cat mylast.py
import re

f = open('customer.csv')

for line in f:

      logger_re = re.compile(
     "logger: ([^ ]+)\
      submit date:(\d+)\
      done date:(\d+)\
      stat:(.+)\
      err:(.+)$")
      myvalues = logger_re.search(line).groups()
      print myvalues

f.close()
```

Exception:

```
# python mylast.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mylast.py", line 13, in ?
    myvalues = logger_re.search(line).groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Comment: What does `print repr(line)` tell you is in your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is not matching your actual file contents.

As such, `logger_re.search(line)` returns `None`.

The problem here is that you **indented** your regular expression but did not compensate for the extra whitespace:

```
logger_re = re.compile(
     "logger: ([^ ]+)\
      submit date:(\d+)\
      done date:(\d+)\
      stat:(.+)\
      err:(.+)$")
```

Note that the whitespace at the start of the line there *matters*. Use separate strings (Python will join them at compile time):

```
logger_re = re.compile(
     "logger: ([^ ]+) "
     "submit date:(\d+) "
     "done date:(\d+) "
     "stat:(.+) "
     "err:(.+)$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search will return `None` if no matches were found. You need to check that `myvalues is not None` before attempting to access `groups()`.